# Avr dude programmer

Tags: attiny, isp, programmer

I was trying to upload a hex file to my attiny85 with an arduino,and I came across this:

```
avrdude -c avrisp (followed by other codes and the flash address )
```

This doesn't work and it gave one of the most famous arduino errors : stk500_getsync() : not in sync: resp=0x00

Then I tried

```
   avrdude -c arduino
```

And the code was successfully downloaded, but the chip itself doesn't work as intended. So this is the question, what does the -c [programmer id] actually do, for example in this case, does it download the hex file to my arduino?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DId you disable the reset on the Arduino after installing the ArduinoISP sketch? If not, then you just reprogrammed the Arduino with your ATTiny85 program.

Comment: @Majenko disable with capacitor at the reset? I just tried and same error code with avrisp.(Also I don't know if I actually prevented the reset or not, no way I know now.) So the arduino option programs the arduino regardless of what chip I choose later ?

Comment: The `-c` selects which protocol to use to talk to the remote device. `-c arduino` selects the Arduino's bootloader as the protocol to use. `-c avrisp` selects the protocol spoken by the ArduinoISP sketch.

Comment: Did you reprogram the ArduinoISP sketch back on the Arduino after breaking it with `-c arduino` and before testing it again with the reset disabled?

Comment: @Majenko the one in the example , yes. I also reburned the bootloader for the attiny85 just in case . Since the data flows from my laptop through the arduino then into the attiny85, does this mean that by selecting -c arduino will download the hex file into the arduino, or download the hex file into the attiny85 with arduino protocol ?

Comment: It sounds like you're not actually doing what you describe (and we assume from the situation) you are doing. Using an Arduino to program an ATTiny85 usually means using it as an ISP to flash the chip directly. Instead it sounds like you are actually using a bootloader on the ATTiny and using the Arduino as a dumb UART interface. Is that correct?

Comment: @Majenko that... Actually sounds like it. All I want is to download my hex file into my attiny85 , and I do not have any other way of connecting the attiny85 to my laptop.

Comment: Yet you seem to have the ability to program the bootloader on the ATTiny? Why not just program the HEX file directly using the same method instead of messing with bootloaders?

Comment: @Majenko I burned the bootloader with the arduino software.(under the tools) I really do not have the ability to properly program an avr device now. And I think I'm not actually burning the bootloader although it says so, as I saw from other forums that I am just actually resetting the clock rate of the chip.

Comment: @Majenko I couldn't use "avrisp" because of the error, and "arduino" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Using an Arduino to program a microcontroller is very crude at best. You should invest in a USBASP from eBay. They're dirt cheap.

Comment: Which bootloader do you think you are installing on the ATTiny?

Comment: @Majenko because of where I live, it's not that easy to obtain these products, eBay included. And this is my one time project, and I won't be returning to avr devices anytime soon (I think).

Comment: @Majenko bootloader wise..... I have no idea. Attiny85 comes with a bootloader...Right?

Comment: You have no idea what bootloader you tried installing? Where did you get it?

Comment: @Majenko here http://my.element14.com/microchip/attiny85-20pu/mcu-8bit-attiny-20mhz-dip-8/dp/1455162?CMP=i-55c5-00001621

Comment: No, I mean the bootloader. Where did you get the bootloader? `I also reburned the bootloader for the attiny85 just in case`

Comment: @Majenko the "burn bootloader" under the "tools" in the arduino ide. Which most likely isn't a bootloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Install ArduinoISP (in the examples menu) on your Arduino board.
2. Disable reset on the Arduino board by adding a 10µF capacitor between the RESET and GND pins.
3. Wire the ATTiny chip to the Arduino following [this schematic](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/arjun/programming-attiny85-with-arduino-uno-afb829).
4. Run the upload command using `-c avrisp` with your program's HEX file

Alternatively you can just install the boards package detailed in the schematic link and program it directly from the Arduino IDE instead of messing with the `avrdude` upload command.

You must also ensure that you are uploading at the right baud rate. The ArduinoISP sketch defaults to 19200 baud:

```
// Configure the baud rate:

#define BAUDRATE    19200
// #define BAUDRATE 115200
// #define BAUDRATE 1000000
```

and you must match that in your `avrdude` command with, for example, `-b 19200`.

Comment: C:\Users\User>avrdude -c avrisp -P com1 -p t85 -Uflash:w:C:\Users\User\Desktop\sd8p_mo.hex:i
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you. (exact code and error returned. also using 22uF capacitor, other forum said it was okay)

Comment: I would suggest you forget using the command line for this. Follow the tutorial I linked to step by step and use the IDE for everything.

Comment: Oh, and is your Arduino *really* on COM1?

Comment: it is. I changed it in the device manager and made sure of it in the arduino ide. The code I want to import is found in hex.(http://elm-chan.org/works/sd8p/report.html), and the tutorial only allows ide, if im right.

Comment: There is source there, just not for the Arduino IDE (or not easily).

Comment: Add `-b 19200` to the avrdude command.

Comment: You can also try `-c arduinoisp`

Comment: Another one to try is `-c stk500v1`. It's really confusing - they have "ArduinoISP", "ArduinoISPOrg" and "ArduinoAsISP" - all to do the same thing and all slightly different. I guess for different versions of the ArduinoISP code.

Comment: HOLY It worked!!! the "-b 19200"!!!! Thank you so much !!!! I know what it means (baudrate right), but why?

Comment: The baud rate has to match the baud rate programmed in the ArduinoISP sketch. That defaults to 19200, but avrdude defaults to 115200.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59376/discussion-between-see-jian-shin-and-majenko).